# Question on Derivative Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_n$ be the polynomials of degree no more than n with basis $Z_n=(1, x, x^2,\dotsc,x^n)$. The derivative transformation $D$ goes from $P_n$  to $P_{n-1}$. Write out the matrix for $D$ from $(P_4, Z_4)$ to $(P_3, Z_3)$.

I haven't done a problem similar to this so I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Thanks

Comment: Hint: The columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have bases
\begin{align*} \alpha &= \{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\} & \beta &= \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}
\end{align*} for $P_4$ and $P_3$ respectively.

Our map $D:P_4\to P_3$ is given by $D(f)=f^\prime$. To compute
$[D]_\alpha^\beta$, we must evaluate $D$ on each basis element in $\alpha$ and
write the output in terms of the basis elements in $\beta$. Doing so gives
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrcr} D(1) & = & 0 & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot 1 &
+ & \color{purple}{0}\cdot x & + & \color{darkcyan}{0}\cdot x^2 & + &
\color{darkorange}{0}\cdot x^3 \\ D(x) & = & 1 & = & \color{blue}{1}\cdot 1 & +
& \color{purple}{0}\cdot x & + & \color{darkcyan}{0}\cdot x^2 & + &
\color{darkorange}{0}\cdot x^3 \\ D(x^2) & = & 2\,x & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot 1
& + & \color{purple}{2}\cdot x & + & \color{darkcyan}{0}\cdot x^2 & + &
\color{darkorange}{0}\cdot x^3 \\ D(x^3) & = & 3\,x^2 & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot
1 & + & \color{purple}{0}\cdot x & + & \color{darkcyan}{3}\cdot x^2 & + &
\color{darkorange}{0}\cdot x^3 \\ D(x^4) & = & 4\,x^3 & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot
1 & + & \color{purple}{0}\cdot x & + & \color{darkcyan}{0}\cdot x^2 & + &
\color{darkorange}{4}\cdot x^3
\end{array}
$$
Hence
$$
[D]_\alpha^\beta= \left[\begin{array}{rrrrr} \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{1} &
\color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} \\ \color{purple}{0} &
\color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{2} & \color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{0} \\
\color{darkcyan}{0} & \color{darkcyan}{0} & \color{darkcyan}{0} &
\color{darkcyan}{3} & \color{darkcyan}{0} \\ \color{darkorange}{0} &
\color{darkorange}{0} & \color{darkorange}{0} & \color{darkorange}{0} &
\color{darkorange}{4}
\end{array}\right]
$$

Answer (score 2):

The matrix of a linear map $L:(V,B) \to (U,C)$ is found by writing $L(b_j)$ in terms of $c_i$ for each $b_j \in B$. In this case,
$$ D(1)=0, \qquad D(x) = 1, \qquad D(x^2)=2x, \qquad D(x^3) = 3x^2, \qquad D(x^4) = 4x^3, $$
so the matrix is
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}. $$
(This takes vectors with five components and gives you ones with four, as it should, and you can check on the general polynomial of degree $4$ that it gives you the right components for the derivative.)